# jquery - is it possible to see if a cached element is hidden or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I've cached a DOM element in jquery and wondered how i can see if it's hidden or not.

I have no problem doing by a normal selector. With a normal selector i'd do something like this if statement:

```
if('.someClass:hidden') {
    console.log('hidden')
} 
else {
    console.log('not hidden');
}
```

But instead of .someClass i had the element cached.  Like this, details being the cached element:

```
$this = $(this);
details = $this.find(".details");
```

Many Thanks

B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for a cached element you can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
var $cachedElement = $('#cachedElement');
if($cachedElement.is(':hidden')){
   console.log('hidden')
}else {
   console.log('not hidden');
}
```